# How to read the whole line?

Tags: python, file, line, try-except

I try to ask user for the line number and display it but it keep showing the first letter not the line.

And I can't figure it out how to loop the IoError and IndexError.

Thank you

This is my code

```
def file_content(file_name):
    user_file = open(file_name, 'r')
    content = user_file.read()
    user_file.close()
    return content
def main():
    file_name = input('Enter the name of the file: ')



    try:
       content = file_content(file_name)
    

    except IOError:
       print ('File can not be fount. Program wil exit.')
       exit()

    try:
    
       line_number = int(input('Enter a line number: '))

    except ValueError:
        print ('You need to enter an integer for the line number. Try again.')

    except IndexError:
        print ('that is not a valid line number. Try again.')

    
    print ('The line you requested:')
    print (content[line_number-1])

 main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`content` is simply the content of the file as your use `read()` - so printing `content[-1]` prints the last thing in content, i.e. the last character.

If you want content to be lines, the a) open the file ‘rt’ and b) read it using `readlines()` which you might need to note includes the line ending with the line:

```
def file_content(file_name):
    user_file = open(file_name, 'rt')
    content = user_file.readlines()
    user_file.close()
    return content
```

Now `content[-1]` is th last line.

Answer (score 0):

barny has a good answer, but [using readlines() isn't a best practice](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/06/readlines-considered-silly.html). You might consider replacing your `file_content` function with something that doesn't load the entire file into memory at once, like this:

```
def file_content(filename):
  result = []
  with open(filename, 'r') as input_file:
    result = list(input_file)
  return result
```